# How to get the reference of fixture within the test function using pytest usefixtures

Tags: pytest, fixtures

The pytest usefixtures is a great feature.
I would like to define it in my test module and have all tests use that fixture.
Need to get the reference of the fixture to retrieve some data.
The reference to the fixture is not available within the test function.
Is the use of usefixtures is only for the side effects?
If true, can this be changed so test function can reference the data within the fixture?

Comment: Are you trying to use a fixture as a parameter for all your tests? Why don't you define the fixture within the conftest.py module of yours root tests folder and then this fixture will be available to all the tests implicitly. And also you can define the scope of the fixture as **session**, so the fixture wont get initialized again and again for each test. The fixture parameter of the test will get the return value of your fixture, if that is what you are expecting. Your fixture can have any logic and the result of that logic can be returned and will be available in your tests.

Comment: I defined a fixture called environments and passed that in as argument to each test and that worked. Then I tried usefixtures and removed the environments as an argument to each test function and I assumed pytest will inject the environments fixture into each test so I can retrieve value from it but that did not work. Looks like pytest does not intend usefixtures to work this way.

Comment: Could you provide a sample to reproduce this, so it will be easy to help

Comment: Declare environments fixture at the module level and have a reference to that fixture to retrieve data to build test1, test2 etc without having to put environments as argument to each test.                                                                                                                                        
    [conftest.py]
    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def environments():
       ...
    [tests.py]
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("environments")
    def test1():
        data = environments["data']
        ...

Comment: **tests/conftest.py content**
@pytest.fixture
def test_envs():
    return ["dev", "staging"]
**tests/test_example_fixture.py** content:

def test_fixture(test_envs):
    print("Fixture values:", test_envs)
    assert test_envs == ["dev", "staging"]

Now run: **pytest tests/test_example_fixture.py -s**
It should run the tests and prints the fixture value
Fixture values: ['dev', 'staging']

Comment: @FelixKJose Thanks for your response. I understand your point. That was what I tried first. I was hoping that by using pytest.usefixtures for that fixture at the module level that I do not have to add the fixture name as an argument to each test function. Sounds like that is not supposed to work. What I really wanted is a way to get a reference to the fixture. I see with autouse I can get the side effect of running the fixture but there the reference to the fixture is also not available to the test function.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible and not supported. You have to use them as a parameter to the test, incase you want it is return value.